# Flutter in Chrome can't GET url (due to missing headers?)

Tags: http, flutter, dart, cors

I am trying

```
http.get(url, headers:{"myHeader": "foo"});
```

But the Java servlet receives the request with HTTP method OPTIONS instead of GET (?!) and the Chrome network shows "Failed to load response data".  Could it be that setting an explicit header overrides some default headers (like `Accept` `Connection` `Referer`) which are confusing things and if so can I tell Dart to add a header without losing these default headers? Thanks!

Added a pic from Chrome Network to show the missing headers
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that as per the CORS protocol the java servlet defaults to not accepting requests from your flutter client. So the fix needs to be applied to the java servlet (and or the web server).

I had to do the same thing with a PHP script running on an Apache web server. I added these two lines to an .htaccess file in the directory containing the script:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "myHeader"
```

And these two lines to very top of the PHP code:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: myHeader");
```

I think it's only necessary to update the .htaccess file OR the PHP script, but at this point I'm just relieved to have finally gotten it running.

Not sure what web server you are running on, but for your servlet you should be able to just enter

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "myHeader");
```

And that should work.

Note that if it does, you will need to go back later and tighten up the origin value. "*" is a wildcard that allows anyone in. You will (most likely) want to restrict that. I haven't figured that bit out yet. I'll post again when I do.

Comment: I guess you mean something like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing.  Thanks that does explain the OPTIONS call?  Question is how to create the request in DART so that it includes the default headers and doesn't cause this problem

Comment: Oh, sorry, I screwed up the link when I edited the post (to remove something that I wasn't   100% certain of, which might have mislead you). I will edit the post. And add in some more info. (as I finally have this working now). Gimme 10 minutes to retype the original post and I think that will see you right. In the meantime, here is the original link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS it is worth reading.

Comment: OK many thanks.  But when my client doesn't set a custom header it all works perfectly.  So my preferred solution is to fix the request on the flutter client side to include all the normal default headers.

Comment: There is nothing to fix on the client. The normal default headers are already there. CORS exists to protect servers from non-default headers (among other things). It's a security mechanism to stop non-authorised clients smuggling non-standard stuff in. If you want to give up on sending myHeader as a header--and send the content in the body instead--that would work. But if you want to send it as a header you have fix the server or the java applet.

Comment: Thanks but that's not the case.  I can see in the Chrome Developer Network that when I set a custom header many other headers get deleted and that triggers a CORS problem which I don't get otherwise.

Comment: OK great point.  Many thanks the key was indeed to add `response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "myHeader");` in the Java servlet!

Comment: Cool. You're the first person I've really helped here, and it helped me clarify my understanding as well so we both win. :)

Answer (score 0):

Putting this as another answer because I know what I'm talking about now, and it will confuse things if I replace the first answer, or just make it too long if I add this.

The answer to the question "Could it be that setting an explicit header overrides some default headers (like Accept Connection Referer)?" is, definitely, no.

I've put together three files so you can prove this to yourself. Sorry, the key one is in PHP rather than Java Applet because that's what I'm using. But it is very very simple so if you aren't able to run PHP on your server you can probably rewrite it in Java farily easily. All it does is echo the url, body and headers within a json response, so that you can see what the server sees when you send it something.

.htaccess

```
#Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
#Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
#Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "From"
```

These three lines, commented out, just remove the # to enable them, are what you need to "fix". They can either be in this file (in this format) OR in the file below (in that format), commented out, just remove the // to enable them . You only need them in one place or the other, but you do need them somewhere. When you run the Flutter app below with both commented out, it will fail. When you run it with either enabled, it will succeed. And you will be able to see that your server is seeing all your headers, including your custom ones.

echo.php

```
<?php
//header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
//header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE");
//header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: From");
//header('Content-type: text/javascript');
echo json_encode(
    (object) array(
        'HTTP_ORIGIN' => $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'],
        'REQUEST_METHOD' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'],
        'url' => $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],
        '$body' => json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')),
        'headers' => getallheaders(),
    ),
    JSON_PRETTY_PRINT
);
?>
```

main.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http; // add http: ^0.12.1 to dependencies: in the pubspec.yaml file
class User {
  String alpha;
  String bravo;
  User({this.alpha, this.bravo});
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {'alpha': alpha, 'bravo': bravo};
}
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  void _handleOnPressed() async {
    final String url = 'http://<REPLACE.THIS.WITH.YOUR.DOMAIN.NAME>/api/v1/echo.php/12345';
    final String body = jsonEncode(User(alpha: 'a1', bravo: 'b2').toMap());
    final Map<String, String> headers = {HttpHeaders.fromHeader: 'R Reid'};
    http.Response response = await http.post(url, body: body, headers: headers);
    print('response.statusCode: ${response.statusCode}');
    print('response.body: ${response.body}');
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: RaisedButton(onPressed: _handleOnPressed)));
}
```

i.e. you have to explicitly allow any 'non-default' headers you want to send in either your applet or in an access control file on your web server.

Note that you will get different results when you run this as the Dart/Flutter app, from a browser address bar, or from something like Postman. Obviously the results you get in your app are the key ones.

Note also that you don't require the Allow-Methods entry if you are just doing GET or POST. But you do need it for the others.

Finally note that once you get everything working, you should tighten up the Allow Origin Access Control. As above (with an asterisk) it is allowing everyone in. The value you get when echoing the origin when connecting via your app will show you what to put in there to restrict it to just your app.

Comment: Very generous of you to provide all this info but I'm not sure that you are right.  I have added a screenshot to my original question, doesn't that look like an issue with how Dart http client handles headers?.

Comment: No problem: articulating it that way helped me to understand what was happening. 
I'm not really familiar with the Chrome Network, so I don't really know the significance of what it appears to be showing but I am certain that cannot be what you think it is. Consider it another way: it makes no sense that the http package of Flutter, which is mature and widely used, would simply stop sending key default headers whenever someone used its standard ability to send extra headers. Nor that your Flutter app would be sending less headers than my Flutter app...

Comment: ... But it does make sense that a server would protect itself from accepting "unusual" headers, unless it was configured to accept them.

Comment: Here is a suggestion though: just add those default headers in to your Flutter app (or into the minimal app I posted) and then see whether they show up in Chrome Network. I suspect that they won't, because I suspect that CN is simply not showing you everything because of the CORS issue; which I still believe has to be solved server-side.